# Mi href no redirecciona

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Tengo una página ya terminada pero me di cuenta que mis botones del header no redireccionan a las paginas que le pongo, este es el código

```html
<header role="banner" id="fh5co-header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <!-- Mobile Toggle Menu Button -->
        <a href="#" class="js-fh5co-nav-toggle fh5co-nav-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"><i></i></a>
           <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo/logo1.png" width="200" height="50" /></a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
              <li><a href="info-empresa.html">Sobre nosotros</a></li>
              <li><a href="comentarios.html">Comentarios</a></li>
              <li><a href="valores.html">Valores</a></li>
              <li><a href="hoteles.html">Hoteles disponibles</a></li>
              <li><a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

si las pongo fuera del header, si lo hace

¿a qué se podría deber este problema?

Comment: A lo mejor tienes un preventDefault() por el js....no se me ocurre ahora mismo mucho más. Revisa el js por si acaso.

Comment: ¿Ya intentaste usar direcciones URL absolutas?

Comment: Hola @JhonyElizer, bienveido a [es.so], seria de ayuda si agregas todo el codigo que este afectando header (ayudanos a ayudarte), puedes hacerlo dandole click a [edit], la idea es tener un [mcve] en todas las preguntas

Comment: ya quedò con el prevetDefault() del js, pero solo de manera local, cuando lo subo a mi servidor no funciona

Answer (score -2):

Intenta con css:

```
.navbar-header>a {
display: block;
}
```

o

```
.navbar-header>a {
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).